# activemq consumer does not receive message when running in JUnit?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

[image]

with the above consumer.class, when it runs in JUnit , it cannot receive message. but when running via `main` method directly, it works well. The following is the invoking code:

[image]

and the JUnit version is 4.10.

So, would anyone give some point? Thanks a lot in advance!

Of course, when running the two invocation, the JMS server has enough messages waiting for consumption.

Answer (score 3):

since your testMq() method just registers a listener and doesn't block the test thread, the test case will just stop.  try adding Thread.sleep(10000) after the listener is registered but before the test case ends...

Comment: thanks a lot for answer.

with the main method, there is no explicit block. so the question is, why is blocked? and Junit not?

Comment: yep, apparently JUnits threading lifecycle behaves differently than just a main method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540152/java-app-lifecycle